# How to deploy a trained reinforcement learning model on a web service

Tags: web-services, reinforcement-learning

I'm planning to make a website where users can play a simple game with a trained AI agent.How to deploy a trained reinforcement learning model on a web service?
Can we use tensorflow? Is convnet.js framework by Andrej Karapathy useful for this?

Comment: Maybe give deeplearnjs a try? https://pair-code.github.io/deeplearnjs/

GPU accelerated computing on the web, and tensorflow inspired API

Answer (score 0):

I have tried convnet.js and also tried other javascript libraries to do same but it is of no use. You will never be able to know what is happening with the neural network. It did not give any significant output even after i trained agent for whole day.

My suggestion is to make python program as a web service, you can use `flask` for that. make a call to the Webservice from the game when there is need to take action. the service will return only actions.  This way you will have advantage of knowing what is running on. you can plot graphs and notice changes very easily.

here is my code snippet for the Web service

```
from flask import Flask  
from flask import request  
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route("/update", methods=['POST'])
def rest_update():
   reward = request.form.get('reward')
   reward = float(reward)
   state = request.form.get('state')
   state = state.split(',')
   new_state = []
   for each in state:
      new_state.append(float(each))

return str(brain.update(reward,new_state))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

update is the function which take reward and state as input and return action. states is input take as string separated by comma(,). 
this method works perfect for my project.

edit: You can use any library for python, whichever is comfortable to you. it can be pytorch or tensorflow or any other.